# Create a QR code that connects device to wifi SSID & opens a URL?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, qr-code, url

Many questions regarding QR are from years ago. My question is, will a single QR handle 2 functions.

What I'm trying to achieve is. A QR which allows user to connect to my Wi-Fi (Hotspot) AND open a desired website. NOT A CAPTIVE PORTAL.

Answer (score 2):

While usages of QR codes can be very versatile, **there are only a few universally standard formats for a QR code, including WiFi and URL, but not as a combination.**

For example, [the common format for WiFi QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Joining_a_Wi%E2%80%91Fi_network) is: `WIFI:S:<SSID>;T:<WEP|WPA|blank>;P:<PASSWORD>;H:<true|false|blank>;;`. Scanning it using a camera/QR code scanner app may trigger an intent to connect to that WiFi. On the other hand, scanning a QR code with a URL format, such as `https://example.com` may open the link in a browser automatically.

However, combining both of them does not mean that it will work for both. On the contrary, it may only recognize the first part or even break for both since it is not one of the recognized formats anymore. E.g. scanning a QR code for `WIFI:S:MySSID;T:WPA;P:MyPassW0rd;;https://example.com`  on Google Pixel 3a, Android 12 with Google Camera app, ZXing Teams's Barcode Scanner app, and WiFi Setting's built-in scanner only lets the user connect to the "MySSID" access point without opening the URL.

For such non-standard formats, the user also needs a custom app that can handle multiple formats simultaneously in a single QR code.